# BizTalk 2010 WCF-WSHttp config

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am having an issue with calling a web service from BizTalk 2010.  I have read a tutorial, many forums on similar issues and followed recommendations.  So far I can not get BizTalk to successfully use the web service provided.

Send Port setup details.

1. WCF type: WCF-WSHttp
2. The web service is used in an orchestration,  logical port is using  “specify later” option
3. Port is a static port
4. Operation name used in logical port  is set to  ‘LogError’ -

`<wsdl:operation name="LogError">
          <soap:operation soapAction="https://www.practicevelocity.com/PVLoggingService/LogError" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>`

5. General tab,  for config of  SOAP Action header,  text box,  a single action  ‘soapAction’ is specified  using the string  from above, namely   -
               `https://www.practicevelocity.com/PVLoggingService/LogError` 
     Security tab,   security mode == None

I seem to be missing / not understanding  which  config(s)  items are improper.
Any further suggestions?

```
Error from Event Properties [ Windows log > Application ]
Log Name:      Application
Source:        BizTalk Server
Date:          9/5/2013 4:30:22 PM
Event ID:      5743
Task Category: BizTalk Server
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.PracticeVelocity.com

Description:

The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "SendPort_PVInfoLoggingService" with URL "http://devlogging.practicevelocity.com/13_3/EDILogService.asmx?". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.ServiceModel.FaultException: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:MustUnderstand</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">SOAP header Action was not understood.</soap:Text></soap:Reason></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)".
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="BizTalk Server" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="32960">5743</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>1</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-09-05T21:30:22.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>58220</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.PracticeVelocity.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>SendPort_PVInfoLoggingService</Data>
    <Data>http://devlogging.practicevelocity.com/13_3/EDILogService.asmx?</Data>
    <Data>System.ServiceModel.FaultException: &lt;soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;&lt;soap:Body&gt;&lt;soap:Fault&gt;&lt;soap:Code&gt;&lt;soap:Value&gt;soap:MustUnderstand&lt;/soap:Value&gt;&lt;/soap:Code&gt;&lt;soap:Reason&gt;&lt;soap:Text xml:lang="en"&gt;SOAP header Action was not understood.&lt;/soap:Text&gt;&lt;/soap:Reason&gt;&lt;/soap:Fault&gt;&lt;/soap:Body&gt;&lt;/soap:Envelope&gt;
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Your exception message is "SOAP header Action was not understood." Most likely you are using wrong action. You can try to import your service to SoapUI (or smth like that) and you'll see the valid action.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Add Generated Items, Consume WCF Service and point it the the endpoint it should generate you two binding files {servicename}.BindingInfo.xml and {servicename}_Custom.BindingInfo.xml.   You can import one of these and you should then have a fully and correctly configured port.  The name will be an auto-generated one which you will want to rename.